# Selecting a function with ternary conditional operator

Tags: c#, function, conditional-operator, c#-8.0

I'm new to C#, coming from a C++ background. In C++ I can do things like this:

```
int function1 (int a, int b, int c) {
    return ...;
}

int function2 (int a, int b, int c) {
    return ...;
}

// Then, somewhere else...
bool condition = ...;
int value = (condition ? function1 : function2)(3, 4, 5);
```

And it will call either `function1` or `function2` — depending on `condition` — and pass the specified parameters to whichever one is called.

My question is, does C# (8.0) have a similar syntax that:

- Selects between two functions based on a condition, and
- Only requires the parameter list to be specified once, and
- Can be done in a single, fairly-readable statement?

If it can do that, what is the syntax?

The only thing I could think of to try was the same syntax as C++, e.g.:

```
int value = (condition ? function1 : function2)(3, 4, 5);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But it just points to the `^`ed section and gives a "Method Name Expected" error (which makes sense, of course). I don't really have any other ideas.

Comment: Consider `int value = (condition ? (Func<int, int, int, int>)function1 : function2)(3, 4, 5);
` to make it explicit. The duplicate explains why your existing code doesn't work.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks! Yeah the dupe has everything else I was looking for and an informative explanation. 

Comment: private void Function1() { }
private void Function2() { }
private void RunFunction(int num) => ((Action)(num == 1 ? this.Function1 : this.Function2))();

This now works in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Func<T1,T2,T3,TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-4?view=net-5.0) should do it

```cs
private int function1(int x, int y, int z) => 1;
private int function2(int x, int y, int z) => 2;

private void main(string[] args)
{
    bool condition = true;
    Func<int, int, int, int> func = condition ? function1 : function2;
    func(1, 2, 3);
}
```

It's two statements though, not sure if it's possible to do it in one like you ask.